# Grant permissions to the code of a bat file on Windows 7 to 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am on Windows 10 and I have a .bat file that renames some folders under File programs and %appdata%.

Example: "ren ccleaner _ccleaner"

If I run CMD as administrator and inside the console I run the .bat file, it works perfectly

But when I run that .bat as administrator directly from the right-click; it doesn't work. It shows me the error "Denied access" on every line. The user has admin rights.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because when you run it from the GUI, it doesn't run from the folder where the file is, but from some arbitrary Windows folder. Try printing the current folder from within the script.

Comment: This happens when you use a program to start your batch file and the batch file isn't calling cmd.exe /c first. Just run cmd.exe /c your_batch.bat

Comment: cmd.exe /c your_batch.bat  is not working.

I already did "cd"s; as I said if I run it opening first the Cmd, it works; sorry I wrote wrong error message, I fixed. It is "denied access"